# Python HTTP authentication with extra parameters?

Tags: python, httprequest, synology

Trying to authenticate with my Synology NAS with Python. When I run this through my browser it works fine

```
http://NAS_IP_ADDRESS:5000/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=1&account=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&session=SurveillanceStation
```

However when I try the following python code

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://NAS_IP:5000/webapi/auth.cgi',auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('USERNAME','PASSWORD'))
print response.text
```

I get this response `{"error":{"code":101},"success":false}`

The error code is "Invalid Parameters" according to the API Doc I have for my NAS.

How can I add the other parameters into my HTTP request?

Comment: well, you can only add argumets into headers, or into the url-path itself

Comment: Thanks. I should have tried that first. This worked.
`response = requests.get('http://NAS_IP:5000/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=1&account=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&session=SurveillanceStation')`